# Javascript or other method to read entire HTML page with speech (offline)

Tags: javascript, html, speech

I'm trying to add a visual impaired option to an HTML5 based kiosk that runs offline. The idea is that once a a button is clicked each page's text is read out loud (only 1 text box per page which is loaded from external txt file) speak.js seems like an option but the voice quality isn't that great. I had a look at some chrome plug ins but they all require you to select the text first. I'd like to try jTalk but still waiting on a download link from the creator - not sure if that will work anyway as this needs to run locally on the windows 7 pc serving as the kiosk. The chrome plugins seem to work nicely but they all require the text to be selected and I'm not sure how I could control text being read or not via n HTMl/JS link anyway. therefore ideally I'd like a Jscript library that would let me execute the command on a page per page basis.

Any ideas / suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think http://www.chromevox.com might have what you are looking for. It's a chrome extension for vision-impaired users and has an api you can use.